# Where to put initscr()?

Tags: c++, ncurses

I am trying to make a Snake game in C++. I am using the ncurses package for key input and I know that I need to put initscr() somewhere to enable key input, but I don't know where. I tried at the top of the main method but that caused unexpected issues with the display. I also tried putting it in the Input() method, but that also became problematic with the display. I don't know where to put it or if I need to add something else to make it work, but can someone help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curses.h>
using namespace std;

bool gameOver;
bool pressed;
const int width = 20;
const int height = 20;
int x, y, fruitX, fruitY, score;
enum eDirection { STOP = 0, LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN };
eDirection dir;

void Setup() {
    gameOver = false;
    dir = STOP;
    x = width / 2;
    y = height / 2;
    fruitX = rand() % width;
    fruitY = rand() % height;
    score = 0;
}

void Draw() {
    system("clear");
    for (int i = 0; i < width + 2; i++)
        cout << "#";
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if (j == 0)
                cout << "#";
            if (i == y && j == x)
                cout << "O";
            else if (i == fruitY && j == fruitX)
                cout << "F";
            else
                cout << " ";

            if (j == width - 1)
                cout << "#";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < width + 2; i++)
        cout << "#";
    cout << endl;
}

void Input() {
    switch (getch()) {
        case 'a':
            dir = LEFT;
            break;
        case 'd':
            dir = RIGHT;
            break;
        case 'w':
            dir = UP;
            break;
        case 's':
            dir = DOWN;
            break;
        case 'x':
            gameOver = true;
            break;
    }
}

void Logic() {
    switch (dir) {
        case LEFT:
            x--;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            x++;
            break;
        case UP:
            y--;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            y++;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

int main() {
    Setup();
    while(!gameOver) {
        Draw();
        Input();
        Logic();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`initscr` should be called "early" (before any I/O).  However, your example shows a mixture of `getch` (possibly curses, could be conio) and stdio (which won't work unless you flush output, switch back/forth to curses)

```
int main() {
    initscr(); // this
    Setup();
    while(!gameOver) {
        Draw();
        Input();
        Logic();
    }
    endwin(); // and this
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about you run the code and tell me what you notice (or if you cba: It breaks the display, as said it would in the question.).